# Allow Reviews to be done from Smartphone App

Tags: feature-request, review, android-app

I have been using/testing the Android smartphone application for the past few days and I must say I really like the whole experience.

The one thing I would like to request is to add the functionality to allow users(obviously with enough reputation) to perform the **review tasks** from the smartphone application only.

I am suggesting this as I feel that its still a lot easier and handy for a user to perform a review from the application than writing a complete answer,so it will add more value to the app too.